# Combining the standard errors of Cohen's Kappa computed for multiple rater pairs

Tags: standard-error, reliability, cohens-kappa

In a study on intra-rater agreement with 8 raters, I have computed Cohen's Kappa for each of the raters and I estimated the standard error of each of the kappa values using the Jackknife method.

To get an estimate of the overall intra-rater agreement, I took the mean of all kappa values. So far so good, but what is the correct way to combine the standard errors? I want to combine these standard errors, so I can compute a 95% CI for the mean kappa.

I first thought that I could combine the standard errors by using the formula for pooled variance ([wikipedia:pooled variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooled_variance), [function in R](https://github.com/cran/fishmethods/blob/master/R/combinevar.R)), with the kappa values as the means, the squared standard errors as the variances and the number of observations as N. However, I am not sure whether this is entirely correct. Can I replace the mean in the formula by the estimated kappa? If this is incorrect, can someone explain it to me from a mathematical point of view and a statistical point of view? Furthermore, I got upper confidence limits > 1 and hence, a value that is impossible for kappa.

Answer (score 1):

There is a version of kappa for the case of multiple raters which is usually attributed to Conger. A quick search with your favourite statistical package should find how to compute it. This is likely to be more productive than trying to average values of pair-wise kappa and then compute a variance for the average.